# Sum within select Div based on class name

Tags: jquery

I have the jquery to sum all of the price for the whole page.  But i want to get a total by section.  Each section is within a div and the id's for each div is unique.

```
<div id="ui-id-1" class="equip-section">
        <textarea class="section-title">Section Title</textarea>
        <span id="sectprice" class="section-price">$0.00</span>
        <div class="Hiderow"><a class="addDrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a></div>
        <div class="equip-item">
            <textarea class="item-name">Item Name</textarea>
            <textarea class="model">Models</textarea>
            <textarea class="cost">$45.00</textarea>
            <textarea class="qty">2</textarea>
            <span class="price">$90.00</span>
        </div>
        <div class="equip-item">
            <div class="delete-wpr">
                <textarea class="item-name">Item Name</textarea>
                <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
                <textarea class="model">Models</textarea>
                <textarea class="cost">$11.00</textarea>
                <textarea class="qty">2</textarea>
                <span class="price">$22.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="equip-item">
            <div class="delete-wpr">
                <textarea class="item-name">Item Name</textarea>
                <a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a>
                <textarea class="model">Models</textarea>
                <textarea class="cost">$6.00</textarea>
                <textarea class="qty">2</textarea>
                <span class="price">$12.00</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ui-id-2" class="equip-section">
        <textarea class="section-title">Section Title</textarea>
        <span id="sectprice" class="section-price">$0.00</span>
        <div class="Hiderow">
            <a class="addDrow" href="javascript:;" title="Add a row">Add a row</a>
        </div>
        <div class="equip-item">
            <textarea class="item-name">Item Name</textarea>
            <textarea class="model">Models</textarea>
            <textarea class="cost">$4.00</textarea>
            <textarea class="qty">1</textarea>
            <span class="price">$4.00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

so I want section ui-id-1 section price to total all of the price within it and ui-id-2 to total all the price within it, etc.   All of this is dynamically generated or I would have created specific names.

**edit - sorry here is a quick and dirty
[jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fEvLk/2/)

note when you change the cost or qty the price updates.  I want the sections to total for each.

Comment: How about a JSFiddle?

Comment: You forgot to post your jQuery.

Comment: plus the `JavaScript` code you have some far it will be great :)

Comment: Completely off the top of my head, so may or may not work... `var total = 0; $.each($('span.price'), function(key, span) { total += parseInt($(span).html()); });` - This only calculates the overall total, so if you want it on a `ui-id-X` basis, edit it.

Comment: question updated with jfiddle example of what i have so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.equip-section').filter(function() {
    var prices = 0;
    $(this).find('.price').map(function() {
        prices += Number($(this).text().replace('$', 0));
    });
    console.log(prices);
});
```

[**Demo Link**](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/wLAjN/)

Comment: while this is totaling like i would like its doing all of the equip-section

Comment: misunderstanding.  I need each section to get price within as it updates.  your first solution was doing this but showing nultiple all at once.  second solution is grouped all.

Comment: See this http://jsfiddle.net/fEvLk/5/   look in js section 76 to 82

Comment: your first solution did work - I just had to add a line replacing the console log.

Comment: At LEAST state where you got the code above (ie. my comment). Always state your sources.

Comment: @Jimbo Your code is not used here, problem solving method is different, if you are trying to point out `each` function and variable name `total` then, best of luck, you should take all the credit

Comment: @ManojYadav No, I'm pointing out that most of it was my work. `each`, `total`, `parse[int|float]`. It doesn't matter what you say, I had it in the comments earlier. I'm not bothered that you answered it. I'm bothered that you didn't attribute where you got the idea - as there are *many* different ways to achieve this (and `$.each()` is one of the poorer, quicker ones imho).

Comment: @Jimbo So, I should use `$.each` differently, not as `defined` by `jQuery` and some how find different method to `parseFloat` when I need to parse. You should have given a proper solution and not claiming other work as your own work. It doesn't mean if you have commented that's why I am using it. It's common sense to do a `each` and add to `total`

Comment: All evidence points to my comment providing an answer, then you more or less ripping it and putting it as your answer. **It's nice to see that you have now removed the copied material.** I do not care about the points - I care about plagiarism. We do not need to discuss this further, thank you for removing the copied code. If you do wish to continue this conversation, don't do it here; feel free to join me and others in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php).